# Dynamically respond to specific links, even if clicked in browser?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to give the user the ability to choose which links to open using my app.

Suppose he enters www.google.com. Then I want my app to appear in the "complete action using" dialog when "www.google.com/about" is clicked.

I understand that I can't programmatically enable/disable intent filters. Maybe there's some other way around this, like enabling an intent filter for all links, and then doing something additional to selectively not display it?

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receivers registered in your `AndroidManifest.xml` can't be turned on/off dynamically.
Haven't tried that but the only thing that MIGHT work is creating a `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically (create an `IntentFilter` that is equivalent to the intent filter you currently have in your `AndroidManifest.xml`) on a background service and register/unregister it when needed.